# App hangs my Windows Phone 7 phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am currently developing an app that seems to hang my Windows Phone 7 phone. If I start the application and then press the home button or use the back arrow and then repeat this several times then the phone actually hangs in the middle of the app start animation and I need to restart the phone.

To troubleshoot this issue I created a new project and removed all my code and put there my xaml and animations only. My xaml with the animations inside are about 2800 lines long. When used under debugger no exceptions are thrown nor any other error messages are shown.

I created a project for demonstrating my issue. Here are the steps to reproduce the problem

1. Open the project in Visual Studio
2. Select Windows Phone 7 Device
3. Run the application.
4. Start using the home or the back button to quit the app and then relaunch it again and again.

   - [Repro_Crash](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2598447/Repro_WP7_Phone_Crash.zip) - This is the project that I am using to reproduce my issue.
   - [Image of the Crash](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2598447/Image_WP7_Phone_Crash.jpg) - from this point I am forced to restart the phone.

I am looking for hints or tips regarding how to figure out what is happening!

Comment: without an example of how to recreate your issue it's going to be very hard to identify the specific issue. Are you trapping unhandled excpetions? Is there anything in the debug output?

Comment: Nothing gets to the debugger at all. The phone just hangs when starting the app. I will try and create an example project and try to post it here.

Comment: It would definitely be good to get an example. Also, once you have the example it should get posted on to the Microsoft support/Connect site - there's no situation in which an app should be able to hang the phone so this is a WP7 bug (IMO!)

Comment: Doe this happen in th emulator or on a real device? If the emultor are you using the latest version? There were some issues with quickly navigating back and forth with early versions of the tools.

Comment: This is phone only. I have not tried to repro this in the emulator

Comment: @Matt - I seem to be having the same issue with quickly navigating back and forth.  I thought I had the latest tools.  Is there a way to tell if I do or not?

Comment: I would enable the emulator console window, hopefully you are able to see an exception or some error which can narrow the search. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS998vp-juE on how to enable the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your project and it runs perfectly fine on my HTC HD7 NoDo. It displays only a large wall of letters without any animations and does not crash the phone. I'm using the latest Mango Beta 2 Refresh SDK.

Comment: I tried with other phone and it worked with no problem. I concluded that my phone has a hardware fault of some sort.

Comment: Did you already tried a full reset back to the default settings with the defective phone? It would be very interesting to see whats keep crashing your phone. Maybe it was just a minor glitch but otherwise it would be a nice bug to report for MS :)